# Excluding Multiple Files in Org-mode Export Function

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode

I'm trying to find the way to exclude multiple files from export tree. For instance, in the following example in  `org-publish-project-alist`, I have `level-0.org` excluded, so it won't be created in `/foo/bar/pub` as well as not in the sitemap.

```
("somewebproject" 
   :base-directory "/foo/bar/src"
   :base-extension "org"
   :publishing-directory "/foo/bar/pub"
   :recursive t
   :exclude "level-0.org" 
   :publishing-function org-html-publish-to-html
   :headline-levels 4 ; Just the default for this project.
   :auto-preamble t
   :auto-sitemap t
   :html-link-up "sitemap.html"
   :html-link-home "index.html"
   :sitemap-title "My Sitemap"
)
```

However, I have an another file called, for example level-1.org that I also want to exclude, making the file into the list, for instance `'("level-0.org" "level-1.org")` doesn't seem to help it either.

Any tips on making it work in the this snippet, or if there are better ways of doing this, that would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution, after reading actual org-mode source code. So I'm answering my own question here.

In short, looks like `:exclude` accepts regular expression, so I could do `level-0.org\\|level-1.org` or in this case `level-..org`.

Comment: Yay! That is I was lacking, a double backslash before a pipeline. Thanks!

Comment: Can someone please explain why the double backslash is needed here?